# When the USB Camera is connected to the Android phone, this message appears

Tags: android

First, it is the permission of the app I created.

```
<application
        android:name=".application.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".view.USBCameraActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
        </activity>
```

If you connect for the first time without running the app,

```
"This app has not been granted record permission but could capture audio through this USB device."
```

A pop-up will appear saying

When you run the app, a permission popup appears again, and the permission to always connect to the default app appears.

Do you have any method or data?

Comment: I have the same problem. I filed an issue at Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/239336999